# This/these kind of + uncountable nouns

Tags: sentence-construction

I would like to say :

> "I have been coming across these kind of news lately that many people who studied abroad become more successful than others who studied in their countries."

but we cannot use 'these' with 'news'.If I say "this kind of news", for me, it does not connote plural sense I want to imply either. So how can I say it properly?

Comment: "..coming across news reports of this kind"?

Comment: You could also say *these kinds of news reports*.

Comment: Also, could you finish the sentence? Depending on how you continue, it may be more appropriate to say ***the** kind of news*

Comment: Yeah, I would use **the** not **this** or **these**.

Comment: @Catija What I am trying to say is here that  when I read newspapers I see often similar articles(stories) for a few years.

Comment: *these kind of news stories* is the way to say it. You use *these* since you have an example of one in front of you. You would not normally use *the* here if you had an example story in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to get a plural sense out of an uncountable noun. We often have alternative ways about talking about things that are normally uncountable in a countable way. So the following are usually uncountable in English:

- information
- milk
- paper

We we want to talk about them in the plural or singular we can often make these words parts of larger phrases. So we see:

- a piece of information
- three glasses of milk
- two pieces of paper

With *news* the easiest way to do this would be to use the compound noun *news stories*. We can use either *this kind of* with a singular noun, or *these kinds of* with plural or singular countable nouns:

- This kind of car
- These kinds of car
- These kinds of cars

However we can never say:

- ***These kind** of... .(X)

The word *this* always goes with the singular noun *kind*, and *these* always goes with the plural, *kinds*.

The Original Poster's best option, therefore, is probably:

- I have been coming across these kinds of news stories lately ...

*Hope this is helpful!*

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your full sentence, it should actually read:

> I have been coming across **the** kind of news lately that [says/states that] many people who studied abroad...
>
> I have been coming across **the** kind of news [reports] lately that [say/state that] many people who studied abroad...

To appropriately use *this* or *these*, the sentence would need to be framed differently:

> I have been coming across this kind of news lately: many people who studied abroad...
>
> I have been coming across these kinds of news reports lately: many people who studied abroad...

You could also say something like:

> Recent news reports seem to say that many people who studied abroad...

Comment: Yes! Your target conclusion will be just fine using *the*. I'll make one minor edit. Stuff in square brackets is optional and makes the statement more formal.